# Calculate the Power Or Number Of Routing Signal

Tags: java, c++, networking, wifi, signals

I need a function in C++ or Java to calculate the number and power of signals coming from Wifi base stations. This function will help me to find the difference between two positions, of a laptop.

( Note : i am so sorry about first questions , because i have bad english , and this Q came with translator with editing from me).

Comment: Maybe this is what you're trying to ask: Suppose the router is at point O. What is the signal strength at a point P?

Comment: This is pretty much the same question that was closed here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820884/function-to-calculate-power-number-any-thing-about-signal-of-routing-closed

It still doesn't make any sense

Comment: LukeN's suggestion from your previous post is good: write the question in your native language too, and maybe someone will wander through who can translate it.

Comment: Is this question asking how to calculate the distance traveled based on the change in signal strength?

Comment: Thanks , no , not same that , 
i will Explane , 
in the room , i will put laptop in the middle , ok ? 
and in the room i have router , 
i make conection between them, 
now , in this position , i have signal with amount of power = 10 ,
if i change position of laptop , signal in new position will be change , 
i need function to calculate amount of power of signal in position one , and position two, to make my laptop (intelligent), because in my program i will put this function and check every 5 mins , if change amount of power of signal, then laptop understand, its position change, thank

Comment: :( , i am sorry and thank you brothers and sisters :(

Comment: The answer will depend on the operating system used.

Answer (score 0):

There is no portable function for that, because it differes HEAVILY across operating systems. In Linux, you can `ioctl` on the device file, on windows... no idea, sorry.

I think for these kind of questions, google is a good match - try searching for "wireless library java c++", or "c++ wifi strength", play around a bit.

Comment: Ah, so the question is not how to calculate the signal strength yourself for some kind of simulation, but how to query the system for it?

Comment: Exactly. You HAVE the query the system for it, because it's the system's job to manage hardware, and if you need access to some details of that hardware, you have to ask the system!

Comment: ahaaa !! ( in my language = i understand :D ) , 
ok , LukeN, Jefromi , Salgar , Kevin Panko , 
THANKS power (google) to interested and help me , 
sultan..

( i will search , and waiting any new answer here)

Comment: I do understand that you have to ask the system. I misunderstood the question as asking for a simple physical formula - though unfortunately walls make it pretty hard to get even a good first-order approximation.